# Open Class extended from ViewPart in another

Tags: java, eclipse, view, swt, workbench

I'm writing a program in Java in eclipse.
I have two classes which extend from the super class ViewPart. 
Now I want to open only one of the classes automatically (that means when I run the program) and the other one should be opened by a button on the UI of the first. But I don't know how to open a ViewPart class manually.

I tried now

ActorCalendar actorCalendar = new ActorCalendar(); 
                try {
                    actorCalendar.getSite().getPage().showView("id", null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);
                } catch (PartInitException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

Here the class ActorCalendar is a class extended from the class ViewPart. This code Block is implemented in a Button at the other class extended from ViewPart. 
But then I get a NullPointerException at the class where this code block is implemented. In the line:

actorCalendar.getSite().getPage().showView("id", null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);

What did I do wrong?

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you !

Comment: I thought you had one view opened automatically and the second view opened from a button in the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActorCalendar actorCalendarView = new ActorCalendar();

try {
                      IViewPart view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("de.uhd.ifi.se.pcm.bppcm.ui.ActorCalendar");
                      if (view instanceof ActorCalendar) {
                       actorCalendarView = (ActorCalendar) view;
                       actorCalendarView.doStuff();
                      }
                     } catch (PartInitException ex) {
                      // showView() can throw an exception if view cannot be shown
                      ex.printStackTrace();
                     }

this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You want [org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.showView(String)](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.html).  That will allow you to open a view by ID.  If your button is in the first view's toolbar, you can get the workbench page from your view using *getSite().getPage()*.

Comment: I tried ActorCalendar actorCalendar = new ActorCalendar();
       actorCalendar.getSite().getPage();
       actorCalendar.showView("id", null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);     and ActorCalendar is a Class extended from ViewPart but then I got a NullPointerException. Do you know what I did wrong? Thanks